# Better performance to a lot of users at same time

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, hibernate, jsf, tomcat

I'm developing a website, that hopefully, will be accessed by more than a million people at same time. It still has only 70k users, and it's already lagging while uploading a file, or just opening pages and stuff..

I use SQLServer, tomcat and apache http server.

i've tried using another tomcat to manage the access to database, but i'm facing another problem, it has to share the same space of the other tomcat to save the uploaded files. and it causes a huge delay uploading..

what can i do to make my website faster?

The website is developed with JSF with richfaces and Java and Hibernate.

Comment: Is it correct, that your main problem is the file upload?

Comment: Perhaps your problem is bandwidth? Can you get throughput stats from your hosting service?

Comment: it's one of the problems when I cluster tomcat, but I believe that soon enough it will have another performance problem cause i'm using jsf + richfaces to a million users... i dunno.. i Wonder what does orkut or facebook uses to develop and make it fast

Comment: is JSF a good choice such a web site ?.. If I were you, I did not choose JSF. It is an huge memory and cpu consumer..

Comment: Before you can make it faster, you need to know why it is slow.  Are you limited by bandwidth?  Are you holding the uploaded files in memory and causing multiple GC events?  Is your write of the uploaded file to disk the limiting factor?

Comment: One more thing-If you are using too many Richfaces components then it can slowdown your site because the way Richfaces render its component is horrible (just check the size of text in view source). I would rather use various components from lightweight JavaScript library such as JQuery.

Comment: I think @Gursel and @JSS hit the nail on the head.  JSF is a monster memory hog.  With the implementation I am familiar with (icefaces) many user interactions include a round trip to the server which itself hurts the user experience (round trip travel time). In addition to that, since every user is often sending requests to the server, the server will be very resource hungry.

Comment: scaling is not designed and learned in  a day or by a question.

Comment: I really hope to know about your website's health (two years after you posted the this question). Were you able to scale to one million users on your site ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Scaling is hard.
2. For some operations scaling is impossible. Even the greatest (Google, Facebook, Amazon) are not free to choose their features; what is offered is often a compromise between "what would be cool" and "what will scale".
3. The question "how to make it faster" is unanswerable without profiling your application.
4. Making any decisions without considering the former point is PLAIN STUPID AND MIGHT PUT YOU IN EVEN WORSE SITUATION.
5. The traditional way of identifying of bottlenecks is to think separately about:

   a) memory (does the system swap?)

   b) cpu (are cpus really busy, or just waiting for the database?)

   c) IO (usually that includes the database and bandwidth)

Depending on where is your problem, totally contradicting things will help. For example if you have plenty of memory and low bandwith, switch JSF to save state on server. This will use more memory, but make requests shorter. On the other hand if bandwitdth is not a problem and memory is, then do the opposite: switch JSF to keep state on the client. This will help to conserve memory (although in this case matters are more complicated: if tomcats in your cluster try to share session data, then saving state on server becomes an IO problem).

You say that the problem is with uploading files. To help, we would need to know: where do you save them? to DB? to filesystem? Are they short or long? How are they processed? Are there any patterns on the usage of the uploaded files (like: "new files are used most of the time")? and probably even more questions would pop up after these had been answered.

For your own sake: close this question. You will get plenty of well-intentioned, and yet misguiding answers like 'drop JSF', 'cluster everything', 'add memory', 'move to GAE or Amazon EC', 'go with a NoSQL database', 'do everything asynchronously, use a message queue', 'do everything on the client with ajax', 'drop ajax, it makes too many requests and kills server'. All of this is meaningless unless you profile, profile, profile, measure, measure, measure - FIRST. And then give as a better defined question.

Comment: This is relatively a good answer and to the OP, read TONS of books. Asking similar questions and expect a simple answer leads nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you access a db, consider to use EJB + CMP. Then follow the following model:

- cluster your application server (e.g. GlassFish) for load balancing
- keep all service calls of one single request in one single node (by only calling local services)

Comment: tomcat is being clustered, but it's making the upload last longer than usual